# Setting the mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb needs some configuration to run.
It needs to create this hierarchy /data/db/. Where can I find mongo files? and where do I create this directories?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command on your terminal:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/
```

It will set the db path as well as start your mongodb server. You can then go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:27017/
```

verify your connection. You should get: "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."